# collapsible TabStrip from MVC Telerik

Tags: html, tabs, telerik

I am trying to have a TabStrip (Telerik MVC control) with some tabs and the content of these tabs to be collapsible. I mean when i click the second time the same tab the content have to collapse. How can i manage it? In Kendo UI is possible to do that. RibbonBar for microsoft office works as i need.

```
@Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip")
    .Items(Sub(items) 
            items.Add.Text("Application").HtmlAttributes(
                New With {.onclick = "onSelect()"})
    .Content(Html.Partial("ApplicationContent").ToHtmlString())
```

Regards,
Duna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Telerik use the jQuery library behind the scene.

The jQuery Tabs Widget provides such an option:

[Tabs - Collapse content](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#collapsible)

I suggest that you clarify this moment at Telerik Support.

Comment: @Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("TabStrip").Items(Sub(items)
                                                  items.Add.Text("Application").HtmlAttributes(New With {.onclick = "onSelect()"}).Content(Html.Partial("ApplicationContent").ToHtmlString())

Comment: So, what are your results? I assume it is better to include this code snippet into your initial post...